# Java errors after do-release update

Tags: java, do-release-upgrade

I did a release upgrade on my box last night as I had a few other problems that were bugging me on my `14.04` version. The problem is, I'm now getting a Java error when trying to launch my Workbench, no matter if existing or new workspace, I get the same error and the log file contains a bunch of Java errors:

```
$ cat  /home/test/WindRiver/workbench-3.3/wrwb/platform/x86-linux2/eclipse/test:9999/.metadata/.log
!SESSION 2017-10-06 09:33:14.585 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130131-0800/WB20151117-1158
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-06 09:33:27.450
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.Env.setEnv(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
        at com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.Env.setEnv(Native Method)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WREnv.setSystemEnv(WREnv.java:805)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.initWorkbenchEnvironment(WRInstallRegistry.java:631)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.init(WRInstallRegistry.java:484)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.getInstance(WRInstallRegistry.java:550)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.checkPreconditions(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:148)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.CopyOfIDEApplication.start(CopyOfIDEApplication.java:136)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.access$2(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:1)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.start(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WRWBMain.main(WRWBMain.java:37)
```

Why is this and how can I get it fixed?

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217329/error-message-when-executing-windriver-workbench-host-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @George Thanks but I already had the suggested packages installed and i still get the error...

Comment: Do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, lets see that will help!

Comment: @George no packages to install....